# UITableView cancels UITapGesture

Tags: ios

uitableviewdidselect cancel outs tap gesture action 
there is an UIImageView in cell.contentView and there is a tap gesture to enlarge the image the control is not going to the Tap Gesture action its passing to the tableview didselect delegate ? I am using UITableView class for my table already did userInteractionEnabled=YES & cancelsTouchesInView = NO

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set

```
tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because table view can't take two user interactions at a time. First it will give priority to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. You need to disable user interaction on cells. So that **tap gesture** will be called. Make sure that `user interaction enabled` for imageView.